# jquery real-time margin update

Tags: jquery

In jquery, How do I set the margin-left of an object via a formula.

```
if browser-width < 2000 {
    (abs(browser width - 2000))/2
}
```

I have a background slider that I want to always be centered, and right now its left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

```
var winW = $(window).width();
var winH = $(window).height();

diffW = winW/2 - ('.foo').width()/2
diffH = winH/2 - ('.foo').height()/2

$('.foo').css({
  marginLeft:diffW,
  left:diffH

})
```

Comment: that works, but how do i get it to adjust in real-time? If you resize the window suddenly you can see where the edge of the slider is

Comment: margin-left works but you will need to body overflow hidden otherwise position:absolute and give left and top position